# How to display date & time on alert box

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am facing error , when alert box clicked. Error is incompatible array pointer with String  .

```
2015-10-14 12:41:06.235 snadwitch2[1974:56154] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f954e918e60
    2015-10-14 12:41:06.239 snadwitch2[1974:56154] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f954e918e60'
```

The alert box code is

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wait" message:@ [@"The current date and time is: %@", [NSDate date]]  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
        [alert show];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing an array instead of a string.  You need:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The current date and time is: %@", [NSDate date]];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wait"
     message:message
     delegate:self
     cancelButtonTitle:@"Delete"
     otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
[alert show];
```